# Как изменить тип Первичного Ключа со string на int в модели User наследуемой от IdentityUser в ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

Не могу изменить первичный ключ в модели наследуемой от `IdentityUser` в ASP.NET MVC. Я создаю только условного `IdentityUser`, без кастомных ролей и не могу никак поменять тип создаваемого Первичного Ключа, возникает ошибка из-за несоответствия Первичного и Внешнего ключей.

При создании миграции выдаёт ошибку:

> The relationship from 'Club.AppUser' to 'AppUser.Clubs' with foreign key properties {'AppUserId' : int?} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.

Когда навожу на `Id` в классе `AppUser` выдаёт:

> AppUser.id скрывает наследуемый член Identity< string >.id. Чтобы текущий член перевыполнял операцию добавите ключевое слово override

и это тоже пробовал.

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Части кода для понимания проблемы:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Pace { get; set; }
        public int? Mileage { get; set; }
        public string? ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public string? State { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Address")]
        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        public Address? Address { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Race> Races { get; set; }
    }
```

Именно в `AppUser` и нужно изменить тип на `int`

```cs
public class Race
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string? Image { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
        public int? EntryFee { get; set; }
        public string? Website { get; set; }
        public string? Twitter { get; set; }
        public string? Facebook { get; set; }
        public string? Contact { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Address")]
        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public RaceCategory RaceCategory { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AppUser")]
        public int? AppUserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser? AppUser { get; set; }

    }

public class Club
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Image { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Address")]
        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        public Address? Address { get; set; }
        public ClubCategory ClubCategory { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AppUser")]
        public int? AppUserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser? AppUser { get; set; }

    }

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Race> Races { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        
    }
```

Comment: Не знаю на счёт `postgresql`, не в тему, в EntityFrameworkCore это делается проще https://metanit.com/sharp/efcore/3.6.php

Comment: Если правильно понял что бы сделать в классе  `AppUser` было  `public string Id { get; set; }` в остальных классах должно быть  `public string? AppUserId { get; set; }`

Comment: Я пробывал в AppUser сделать public string Id { get; set; } и в остальных классах public string? AppUserId { get; set; }, но в postgres колонка Id должна быть целочисленного типа (int, smallint и тд). Нужно именно чтобы в AppUser тип поля Id стал int, а проблема в том, что Identity делает Первичный ключ по умолчанию типа string и никак изменить тип не получается.

Comment: в `Identity`  вот так `public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }` А ошибка ваша говорит что у вас несовместимые типы ключей в таблицах.

Comment: Странно, в сплывающем окне над полем Id высвечивается "AppUser.id скрывает наследуемый член Identity< string >.id." то есть изначально он как string подставлен, то что не соотвествие типов ключей в таблице я понимаю, вот поэтому и пытаюсь изменить главный на int, чтобы все были одного типа, но из-за проблемы описанной выше не могу.

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, int>
```

Если правильно понял о чем идет речь.

Comment: В таком случае выдаёт ошибку: "Не универсальный тип "IdentityDbContext" нельзя  использовать с аргументами типа."

Comment: Попробуйте тогда вместо string использовать генерик аргумент